# monitor hdmi not working

Tags: graphics, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

I can not use the external monitor hdmi.
I just installed ubuntu 12.04 and my configuration is as follows:

**$> lspci | grep VGA**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1)
```

**$> xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768      120.1     60.0  
   960x720       120.0  
   928x696       120.1  
   896x672       120.0  
   960x600       120.0  
   960x540       120.0  
   800x600       120.0     60.3     56.2  
   840x525       120.0    119.8  
   800x512       120.3  
   700x525       120.0  
   640x512       120.0  
   720x450       119.8  
   640x480       120.0     59.9  
   680x384       119.6    119.9  
   576x432       120.1  
   512x384       120.0  
   400x300       120.6    112.7  
   320x240       120.1  
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**$> nvidia-debugdump -D -v -z -l**

```
nvmlInit succeeded
Listing all GPUs.
Found 1 NVIDIA devices
Warning: nvmlDeviceGetSerial: Not Supported
    Device ID:              0
    Device name:            GeForce 610M
    Device handle:          0x464e1608
    GPU internal ID:        GPU-e367825c-85a8-25b9-94cd-a3c52aaf2785
```

**$> lshw -c display | grep driver**

```
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

**$> glxinfo**

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
        GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
        GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, 
            GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
        GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
        GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_NV_multisample_coverage
    client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
    client glx version string: 1.4
    client glx extensions:
        GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_SGI_video_sync, 
        GLX_NV_swap_group, GLX_NV_video_out, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig,
GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control,
GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
        GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_NV_float_buffer, 
        GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
            GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
            GLX_NV_present_video, GLX_NV_copy_image,
GLX_NV_multisample_coverage, 
    GLX_NV_video_capture, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
        GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
        GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
        GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, 
            GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
        GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
        GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_NV_multisample_coverage, 
        GLX_ARB_get_proc_address
        OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
        OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 610M/PCIe/SSE2
        OpenGL version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 319.32
        OpenGL shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
        OpenGL extensions:
            GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays,
GL_ARB_base_instance, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, 
        GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility, 
        GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage,
GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, 
        GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float,
GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers,
GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
        GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
        GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions,
GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
        GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, 
        GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
            GL_ARB_geometry_shader4, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, 
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel,
GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_imaging, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays,
GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, 
        GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, 
        GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_multisample,
GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, 
        GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters,
GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
        GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_ARB_robustness, 
        GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects,
GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, 
        GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, 
        GL_ARB_shader_image_size, GL_ARB_shader_objects,
GL_ARB_shader_precision, 
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, 
        GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
        GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack,
GL_ARB_shading_language_include, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow,
GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader,
GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, 
        GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
        GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc,
GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
        GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
        GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
            GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
            GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, 
        GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle,
GL_ARB_texture_rg, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
        GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
        GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query,
GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
        GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
        GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
            GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit,
GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program,
GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_viewport_array, 
        GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_texture_float, 
        GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_S3_s3tc,
GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_bindable_uniform,
GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
        GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract,
GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_Cg_shader, GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test,
GL_EXT_direct_state_access, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced,
GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXTX_framebuffer_mixed_formats, 
        GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_geometry_shader4, 
        GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, 
        GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
            GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels,
GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex,
GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
        GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store, 
        GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side,
GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_array,
GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, 
        GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
        GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
        GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
            GL_EXT_texture_lod, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias,
GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
        GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
GL_EXT_texture_storage, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query,
GL_EXT_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra,
GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit, 
    GL_EXT_x11_sync_object, GL_EXT_import_sync_object,
GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_KHR_debug, GL_KTX_buffer_region, 
        GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_compute_program5,
GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image,
GL_NV_depth_buffer_float, 
    GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_draw_texture, GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility, 
        GL_NV_explicit_multisample, GL_NV_fence, GL_NV_float_buffer, 
        GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_fragment_program,
GL_NV_fragment_program_option, 
    GL_NV_fragment_program2, GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage, 
        GL_NV_geometry_shader4, GL_NV_gpu_program4,
GL_NV_gpu_program4_1, 
    GL_NV_gpu_program5, GL_NV_gpu_program5_mem_extended, 
        GL_NV_gpu_program_fp64, GL_NV_gpu_shader5, GL_NV_half_float, 
        GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_multisample_coverage, 
            GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint, GL_NV_occlusion_query, 
            GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil,
GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
        GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite,
GL_NV_primitive_restart, 
    GL_NV_register_combiners, GL_NV_register_combiners2, 
        GL_NV_shader_atomic_counters, GL_NV_shader_atomic_float, 
        GL_NV_shader_buffer_load,
GL_NV_shader_storage_buffer_object, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
        GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
        GL_NV_texture_expand_normal, GL_NV_texture_multisample, 
            GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_texture_shader,
GL_NV_texture_shader2, 
    GL_NV_texture_shader3, GL_NV_transform_feedback, 
        GL_NV_transform_feedback2, GL_NV_vdpau_interop,
GL_NV_vertex_array_range, 
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range2, GL_NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit, 
        GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
        GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_NV_vertex_program2, 
            GL_NV_vertex_program2_option, GL_NV_vertex_program3, 
            GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
                GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_lod,
GL_SGIX_depth_texture, 
    GL_SGIX_shadow, GL_SUN_slice_accum
```

**$> less /etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```